# How to find out if app_offline.htm is giving out 404 or 503 error

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp-classic

I have set app_offline.htm to my root directory and it works nicely to shut the site down and only show that page. Knowing for some frameworks (ASP.Net 2), this file will yield error 404 instead of 503, I want to check what code does my site return (for SEO purpose). However, when I enter a file url, instead of return me any error, it always goes back/redirects to the app_offline page automatically. How could I check to see my app pool is returning 404 or 503 now?

P.S. I heard ASP.NET 4 (the one I use) is now always return 503. But I just want to double make sure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Internet Explorer together with [the ieHTTPHeaders add-in](http://www.blunck.info/iehttpheaders.html).

By using this add-in you see the detailed headers being sent and received in your browser.

E.g. the following is an excerpt when navigating to Stack Overflow:

[image]

As you can see the first request (in black font) is being answered (in blue font) with a status code of **200**.

So in your case, simply open the ieHTTPHeaders add-in and then navigate to your app_offline.htm website.